# stuck in hole on minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am stuck in a hole in minecraft 50-125 bricks deep and I only have flint on full game! I can't kill myself and I am very stuck. Please tell me how to get up as soon as possible

Answer (score 5):

You will have to dig yourself out. Simple begin to build a staircase up to the surface. If you have tools its easy if not have a fun time.